# Exporting Variables from Read

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables

I'm asking the user to input some data using Read that data will be save on a variable that is going to be use in another shell script. However, for some reason is not working.

This is what I got in shell **script1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter Your Full Name: " Name
export Name
sudo bash script2.sh
```

**Script2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $Name
```

My understanding was that if I run sudo bash script1.sh is going to take the input and make it in a variable and using export I can export this to another script.

BTW I'm using Bash Version 4.3.11

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong ? My goal is to ask the user their full name and in another script use their full name.

Comment: What you're doing *wrong* is you're calling a suid executable - one *designed* to pass on its own elevated privileges - with unsanitized arbitrary user-provided environment. `sudo` sanitizes environment by default - thankfully - but what you're doing is a deadly sin. 700 hail mary's and 400 our father's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **No Sudo Option**

You can use the source command to run another bash script in the same environment you came from. (Without launching a subprocess)

**Script1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter Your Full Name: " Name
source script2.sh
```

**Script2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $Name
```

--

## **With Sudo**

The reason your example doesn't work is because of the sudo. You can use Sudo -E option to keep the enviroment variables with the super user environment.

**Script1.sh**

```
   #!/bin/bash
   read -p "Enter Your Full Name: " Name
   export Name 
   sudo -E bash script2.sh
```

**Script2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $Name
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you are writing both scripts yourself, why not pass the variable as part of the parameter?